# onChange is not working in React Native but it is working in React JS

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

onChange ={ (e) => setName(e.target.value) }

const [name , setName] = useState("");
it is not working in React native but at the same time it is working in React JS. I also use onChangeText, it also not working

Comment: Please precise "is not working", and please indicate the versions of React and React-native that you are using.

Comment: "react-native": "0.64.2", Version

Comment: You need to understand that useState actually works, just not in your particular code and setup. So you have to specify what is different in your code by sharing your code and its environment (which includes the react version, because in early versions, useState did not even exist). And "it does not work" is not clear enough to tell us how to fix it, since we don't know what the actual problem is. Does it throw an error, does it just do nothing ? Have you tried to console.log inside the callback ?